# Использование UUID в качестве уникального ключа с кластеризованным индексом

Tags: база-данных, uuid

Чем плох UUID в качестве PK в БД с кластеризованным индексом если проблему с `INSERT` можно исправить самобалансирующимся деревом? Знаю, что без дерева вставка в таблицу может потребовать перестановку всей таблицы, однако если хранить в самобалансирующемся дереве поиска, то при миллиарде записей будет обход максимум 30-40 записей в дереве.

Comment: А тут ответы читали https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144808/is-guiduniqueidentifier-not-suitable-for-a-clustered-index ? Хотя это не совсем то, но всё-таки

Comment: @CrazyElf почитал, там пишется о вставках и о том, что это замедлит вставку, но это не совсем то, как вы и сказали